# HashLocationstrategy not working in angular 6 application

Tags: c#, html, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I'm working on angular 6 application. I want to use HashLocationstrategy in my application. My UI looks like this:
[image: My UI looks like this.]

So, now when the user clicks the "Link Sub Campaign" i'm taking the user to a new tab in the browser to select the required sub campaign to bind and post linking i'm returning the user to my angular application. Now when returning the user to my application, I want to return the user with a Hash.

For example: http://localhost:4200/#/campaign-details/2 ( **Required Format** )
             http://localhost:4200/campaign-details/2 ( **Actual Format I am getting** )

Here is how my Component.html looks like:

```html
<div class=" text-center">
  <h3 *ngIf="!SubCampaign">{{SubCampaign}}</h3>

  <a href="http://localhost:64674/portal/Campaigns/Edit/{{CampaignId}}" target="_blank" *ngIf="SubCampaign == null" class="btn btn-outline-primary "> <i class="zmdi zmdi-link zmdi-hc-fw"></i>Link SubCampaign</a>

</div>
```

And then the above link will take him to my back end which is a C# (web API) and my controller looks like this:

```js
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Campaign campaign = db.Campaigns.Find(id);
            var subcampaign = db.SubCampaigns.Select(x => new {x.Id , x.Name }).ToList();

            if (campaign == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var cId = db.Campaigns.Where(x => x.Id == id);
            ViewBag.cmapId = cId;

            ViewBag.CampaignName = campaign.Name;

            ViewBag.SubCampaigns_Id = new SelectList(subcampaign, "Id", "Name");

            ViewBag.Department_Id = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", campaign.Department_Id);
            ViewBag.BeneficiaryGroup_Id = new SelectList(db.BeneficiaryGroups, "Id", "Name", campaign.BeneficiaryGroup_Id);
            return View(campaign);
        }
```

The above snippet has a view ( .cshtml ) for selecting sub-campaign. **NOTE:** (**Didn't mention the view code here.**)

The http Post method for the above code looks like:

```js
 [HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Department_Id,Name,IsIVRCampaign,BeneficiaryGroup_Id,SubCampaigns_Id")] Linksubcampaign campaign)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Entry(campaign).State = EntityState.Modified;
                //db.SaveChanges();
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                var subcamp = db.SubCampaigns.Where(x => x.Id == campaign.SubCampaigns_Id).FirstOrDefault();

                subcamp.Campaign_Id = campaign.Id;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.campId = campaign.Id;
                return View("ReturnUrl", new { CampaignId = ViewBag.campId });
            }
```

And I'm taking user to a "**RetrunUrl**" action method where I take back user back to the angular 6 application. The **RetrunUrl** action method controller and view page ( .cshtml ) page looks like this.

```js
 public ActionResult ReturnUrl(int? CampaignId)
        {
            ViewBag.CampId = CampaignId;
            return View();
        }
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
    <form action="http:localhost:4200/#/campaign-details/@ViewBag.CampId" method="post" id="returnForm">

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('form#returnForm').submit();
    }, 2000);

</script>
```

my app module looks like this:

```js
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { CampaignDetailsComponent } from './campaign-details/campaign-details.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CampaignService } from './../../services/campaign.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2GoogleChartsModule } from 'ng2-google-charts';
import { CampaignHeaderComponent } from './campaign-header/campaign-header.component';
import { CountToModule } from 'angular-count-to';
import { QuestionnaireComponent } from './questionnaire/questionnaire.component';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { TreemapComponent } from './treemap/treemap.component';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CampaignDetailsComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CampaignHeaderComponent,
    QuestionnaireComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    TreemapComponent
    
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    CountToModule,
    Ng2GoogleChartsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      
      {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
      {path:'campaign-details/:Id',component:CampaignDetailsComponent}
      
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    CampaignService,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here exactly is my problem. It is not returning with a hash value. Even I tried explicitly to keep a hash. Any suggestions where i'm going wrong. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me your app.module.ts file.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar Sir, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick update here, I figured my own solution. It worked as for my requirement. Dropping it here just in case somebody need it. :)

```html
@*This code is my "ReturnUrl.cshtml"*@

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.open('http://localhost:4200/#/campaign-details/@ViewBag.CampId', '_self')
  });
</script>
```